# Does instantiating a runnable ahead of time help increase performance?

Tags: java, android, runnable

I'm designing a game which requires fast animations which I'm implementing using handlers and runnables.

For example:

```
public void animateSomething(){
final Handler h = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
public void run()
{
xxx.setImageDrawable(...);
h.postDelayed(this, 20);
}
};
h.post(r);
}
}
```

My question is: Does declaring the runnable at starttime and only posting it in the "animateSomething()" function has any impact on performance or there isn't any difference between declaring the runnable in a function and posting it afterwards?

Comment: Premature optimization is premature. Aside from that, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: if you have many Runnables and you care about performance you can get rid of them and use Messages instead of Runnables

Comment: I do have many runnables and most of them are running at the same time and I'm noticing some lag in my game that is why I was asking.

Comment: so instead of post()/postDelayed() try to use send[Empty]Message()/send[Empty]MessageDelayed() and handle it in Handler's handleMessage()